# Get url query string of a redirected page to the template engine of express js application

Tags: node.js, express

I am working in a express js application and I need to bind the query string of redirected page into the template engine (ejs) of express applciation. I already walked through the internet but most of the results I am getting only for the parameters supplied from res.render() method not for res.redirect(). kindly anyone please help me to get the proper result

```
exports.save = (req, res) => {
    var category_name = req.body.category_name;
    conn.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        connection.query(`INSERT INTO categories(category_name) VALUES('${category_name}')`, (err, result) => {
            connection.release();
            console.log('result', result);
            if(!err){
                var string = encodeURIComponent('Category added successfully');
                res.redirect("/category/view?msg="+string); // this is my query string
                console.log("Error in listing data" + err);
            }
        });
    })
};
```

In the above code `res.redirect("/category/view?msg="+string);` I have passed my query string as msg. This needs to be collected from template engine like as below

`<%= msg %>`

Please help me